# Java/Groovy regex parse Key-Value pairs without delimiters

Tags: java, regex, groovy, regex-greedy

I have trouble fetching Key Value pairs with my regex

Code so far:

```
String raw = '''
MA1
 D. Mueller Gießer 
MA2 Peter 
Mustermann 2. Mann  
MA3 Ulrike Mastorius Schmelzer 
MA4 Heiner Becker s 3.Mann
 MA5 Rudolf Peters 
Gießer 
'''

Map map = [:] 
ArrayList<String> split = raw.findAll("(MA\\d)+(.*)"){ full, name, value ->  map[name] = value }  
println map
```

Output is:
[MA1:, MA2: Peter, MA3: Ulrike Mastorius Schmelzer, MA4: Heiner Becker, MA5: Rudolf Peters]

In my case the keys are:
MA1, MA2, MA3, MA\d (so MA with any 1 digit Number)

The value is absolutely everything until the next key comes up (including line breaks, tab, spaces etc...)

Does anybody have a clue how to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Sebastian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture in the second group all that follows after the key and all the lines that do not start with the key

```
^(MA\d+)(.*(?:\R(?!MA\d).*)*)
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(MA\d+)` Capture **group 1** matching MA and 1+ digits
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
  - `(?:\R(?!MA\d).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with MA followed by a digit, where `\R` matches any unicode newline sequence
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CPRbzT/1)

In Java with the doubled escaped backslashes

```
final String regex = "^(MA\\d+)(.*(?:\\R(?!MA\\d).*)*)";
```

Comment: Thank you! I just found one more scenario where this regex has problems:
If the Key doesn't start in a new row, it won't recognize it as another match.

Comment: @blickfangQ2 I see, I missed that case. So you mean like this then? https://regex101.com/r/eA9I5b/1

Comment: The second Link shows the problem, yes. I have hundreds of these in an excel file and the variations are extreme. Some write MA2 in a separate line, some make a tab, some just add 20 spaces. The inconsistency is huge with that textfield. So my thought. Just take absolutely everything until the next Key coms up. And if there is no other key, take all until the end.

Comment: just recognized you actually solved it with the second link! I escaped the special characters for java and it seems to work, awesome! :)
`final String regex = "(?s)\\b(MA\\d+)(.*?)(?=MA\\d|\$)"`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(?ms)^(MA\d+)(.*?)(?=\nMA\d|\z)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/NOkli9/1).

**Explanation**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?ms)                    set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                           matching start and end of line) (with .
                           matching \n) (case-sensitive) (matching
                           whitespace and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MA                       'MA'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character (0 or more times (matching
                             the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MA                       'MA'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \z                       the end of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```